# Swift_Transport не отправляется почта с yandex

Tags: php, laravel, email, яндекс-почта

Пользуюсь laravel 5.1 пытаюсь отправить почту с помощью smtp.yandex.
В .env следующие данные:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<my_name>@yandex.ru
MAIL_PASSWORD=<my_password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM=<my_name>@yandex.ru
MAIL_NAME=<my_name>
```

Возвращает ошибку:

```
Swift_TransportException in AuthHandler.php line 181:
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "<my_name>@yandex.ru" using 2 possible authenticators
```

Почта и пароль, гарантированно верные (с помощью Ctrl+C Ctrl+V заходил в свой аккаунт)
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы ведь включили возможность использования почтовых клиентов в аккаунте на яндексе (см. https://yandex.ru/support/mail/mail-clients.xml)?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, да, конечно

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробывать изменить настройки в config/mail.php и использовать tls вместо ssl

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
'port' => 587,
'from' => [
    'address' => 'my_name@yandex.ru',
    'name' => 'my_name',
],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'my_name@yandex.ru',
'password' => 'my_password',
```

Answer (score 0):

После регистрации аккаунта на yandex.ru (без указания телефона) доступ к сервисам ограничен. Чтобы увидеть отладочную информацию добавьте логгирование:

```
$logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));
```

В моём случае в логе обмена с smtp было такое:

```
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Your message looks like spam. You need to use web for sending or prove you are not a robot using the following link http://ya.cc/6lI4
```

Надо перейти по ссылке, привязать к аккаунту номер телеофна и отправка заработает.